# Cannot validate recursive schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm stuck on writing a correct json schema for my data.

Condition:

1. directory is an recursive object with optional property `"$meta"`
2. file can be string or object

   if **file** is object it can have optional property `"$meta"` with oneOf **`"$data"`** or **`"$stringData"`** not both.

JSON Data:

```json
{
  "dir1": {
    "dir1A": {},
    "dir1B": {
      "dir1B01": {
        "dir1B0101": {},
        "dir1B0102": {},
        "dir1B0103": {},
        "file1B.txt": {
          "$meta": {},
          "$data": "ooo",
          "$stringData": "Netus et malesuada" // here should failed
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dir2": {
    "file2.txt": "dolor sit amet" // here should OK but failed
  },
  "file1.txt": "Lorem Ipsum"
}
```

Schema:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://example.com/dir.schema.json",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
      "^[^\\/?%*:|\"<>]+$": { // failed if name consist of invalid chars
        "$ref": "#/$defs/directory"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "$defs": {
      "file": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "$data": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "base64 encoded data"
              },
              "$stringData": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "not": {
                  "anyOf": [
                    {
                      "required": [
                        "$data",
                        "$stringData"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "required": [
                        "$data"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "required": [
                        "$stringData"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "directory": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/file"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "$meta": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "additionalProperties": true,
                  "properties": {
                    "createdAt": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "size": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    },
                  }
                }
              },
            "patternProperties": {
              "^[^\\/?%*:|\"<>]+$": {
                "$ref": "#"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Live Demo: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/HNFtNfRw

Thank you for help

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: I still cannot write a rule for validating property `file` with mixed types string or object. When `$defs/file` is mixed types it passes all assertions https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/VdklNIvX but `file` object should match `$defs/object-file`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues, so let's walk through deriving this schema one step at a time.

Let's start with the object representation of a file. Here's the easy part.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$meta": { "$ref": "#/$defs/meta" },
    "$data": { "type": "string" },
    "$stringData": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

Then we need to add the assertion that one and only one of `$data` or `$stringData` is required. The `oneOf` keyword can express this cleanly.

```json
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["$data"] },
    { "required": ["$stringData"] }
  ]
```

Only one of the schemas can validate to true. If both properties are present, the schema will fail.

Next, let's define a file can be represented as a string or an object.

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    { "type": "string" },
    { "$ref": "#/$defs/object-file" }
  ]
}
```

Notice that we are using `anyOf` instead of `oneOf` in this case. `anyOf` passes validation as soon as one of the schemas is valid. If the first one passes validation, it doesn't need to check the second one. If `oneOf` is used, the validator needs to check both schemas because `oneOf` requires that only one of the schemas passes validation and the rest fail. Because one of these schemas is a string and the other is an object, it's impossible for any JSON data to be both a string an object. Therefore, using `oneOf` only makes the validation less efficient.

That covers files, let's do directories next.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$meta": { "$ref": "#/$defs/meta" }
  },
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[^\\/?%*:|\"<>]+$": { "$ref": "#/$defs/file-or-directory" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

The recursive reference part is pretty simple, but we have a problem with the `$meta` property. `$meta` matches the regular expression in `patternProperties`, so `$meta` will need to validate against `#/$defs/meta` *and* `#/$defs/file-or-directory`, which is not what you want. What you need is something like an `additionalPatternProperties` keyword, but since that doesn't exist, you need to change your `patternProperties` regex to exclude `$meta`. Something like this, `"^[^\\/?%*:|\"<>]+(?<!\\$meta)$"`.

Now all that's left is a schema to express that something is a file or a directory.

```json
  "anyOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/$defs/file" },
    { "$ref": "#/$defs/directory" }
  ]
```

Again, we want to use `anyOf`, but there's a bit more to this than you might notice at first glance. The problem is that something that matches the file schema will also match the directory schema. So, we can't use `oneOf` and the file schema needs to come first. If the directory schema was first, it would incorrectly validate files as directories. When the file schema comes first, it checks if it's a file first and the false positive that we would get from the directory schema becomes irrelevant.

I'll leave it to you to put the pieces together into a full schema, but leave a comment if you have any issues.

Comment: I rewrite the schema https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/0pD9HY3L 
but still have an issue `$defs/file` does not match any property values whose value is string.
file1.txt and file2.txt raise errors.

When rewrite `$defs/file` with mixed types `{ "type": ["string", "object"] }`
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/VdklNIvX
validation passed but it **should failed** because file1B.txt does not match `$defs/object-file`
tested by change encoded string to normal string {file1B.txt: {$data: "Hello"}}

I'm not sure I do something wrong.

Comment: `/$defs/file` should not have a `type` keyword. Including it with `"type": ["string", "object"]` works, but it's superfluous. 

You're still using that unnecessary `not`/`anyOf`/required` pattern. The second code block in this answer shows how to do that much more concisely. 

`contentEncoding` is just an annotation. It doesn't validate anything.

Comment: `/$defs/object-file/not/anyOf/required` also needed for mutually exclusive property `$data` and `$stringData`.
I observed when `/$defs/file` is not mixed (object only) https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/psVEbuTh or https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/asqRmSCD, file1B.txt is matched to `/$defs/object-file`.
But when `/$defs/file/anyOf` is mixed of [`string`, `object`] or [`object`, `string`] https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/HmD809EI, validator seems to ignore `/$defs/object-file`.
Is this a validator bug?

Comment: `oneOf` is already a mutually exclusive assertion. You only need the `not` because you used `anyOf` where you should have used `oneOf`. I didn't mean for you to remove _all_ `type` keywords from `/$defs/file`, just the one at the top. You still need the one in the `anyOf` to assert that the file can be a string. I don't understand what the problem is from your last example. It looks like it's working correctly and as I expect it to. Here's an example of how I would write this schema. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/hAJ76wvv